# emberjs form action target empty parameter

Tags: ember.js

I have a following code inside the application template, i "post" this form to the posts controller, but when I want to get the value of searchField i get undefined.

```
<form {{action "search" on="submit" target="controllers.posts"}}>
  {{input value="searchField" name=searchField}}
  <input type="submit" value="search"/>
</form>
```

Posts controller

```
actions: {
search: function() {
  console.log(this.get('searchField'));
  this.set('search', this.get('searchField'));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it, but I'm going to be frank, this is really unorthodox and out of scope.

It would make a lot more sense to have the action in the controller where the template is so you don't need to target a different controller, and then don't need to access the property off the different controller from the action.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/guxufaxi/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You should not put "" to bind values and it is better to write actions in controller. 
Try this:

```
<form {{action "search" on="submit"}}>
    {{input value=searchField name="searchField"}}
    <button type="submit"> Search </button>
</form>

App.PostsController = Em.Controller.extend({
    searchText: '',
    actions: {
        search: function() {
            var searchText = this.get('searchField');
            console.log(searchText);
            this.set('searchText', searchText);
        }
    }
});
```